# Why isn't the array formula applying to the entire column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a formula in cells F1 and G1 of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yrT1AaZSgwRNmDCLKTG5SKJ_auM6j93q2qhWV3o842w/edit#gid=1741896539). I want to keep the text that is in cells F/G8 and F9&G9 however it's giving me an error. Note that the formula is in an array so that it can apply retroactively to all of the cells in the column.

Here is the code used in Cell F1:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY('Raw Logs'!C2:F, "select C,sum(F) group by C label sum(F)''"), 4, 0)))`

Here is the code used in Cell G1:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY('Raw Logs'!C2:H, "select C,sum(H) group by C label sum(H)''"), 6, 0)))`

Additionally, the data from the formula in Cell C1 is no longer populating (it was before) - the error says it can't because it's unable to overwrite C9 however there was text in C9 earlier and the data from the formula was still populating.

Here's the formula used in Cell C1:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,'Roster Registrations'!F1:G,2,FALSE)))`

Any tips on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array formula needs a space to roll out - that's why. if you want to run it from that 1st row delete cells F8:F9 and use:

```
={"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"Total for February"; 
 "Activity"&CHAR(10)&"Hours"; ""; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B11:B&"", TEXT(QUERY('Raw Logs'!C2:F*1, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col4)''"), {"@", "[h]:mm:ss"}), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]

---

for G1 fx delete G9 and use this in G1:

```
={"";"";"";"";"";"";"";""; 
 "Number of"&CHAR(10)&"Tests"; ""; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B11:B, QUERY('Raw Logs'!C2:H*1, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col6) 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and Col1 <> 0
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col6)''"), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: @ReggyB yes, see the answer for G1

Comment: Gotcha - so those formulas work perfectly there's just one issue I'm seeing. Whenever there's a new submission - the formula that I use to calculate the time duration is overwritten. For example, I tried =ARRAYFORMULA(E2:E-D2:D) so that the formula could be applied retroactively to any new submissions coming in but when I do that to the original column where the info gets imported from - it imports successfully but it sorta breaks when it tries to run the above formula for column F.

Comment: not rly sure whats your issue... can you explain in more detail or with some example in your sheet?

Comment: Hopefully this video helps you a bit more! https://streamable.com/b1vrg4

Comment: try like this: `={"Activity Hours"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,E2:E-D2:D))}` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyFlH.png

Comment: That also worked - and then I believe my last question is how would I make it so that the new submissions are automatically formatted in "Duration". I tried this formula to no avail:
`={"Activity Hours"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="[h]:mm:ss",,E2:E-D2:D))}`

Comment: try:`={"Activity Hours"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(E2:E-D2:D, "[h]:mm.ss")))}`

Comment: It changes the formatting correctly but then it breaks the import.

Comment: if you mean F1 then you can do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewFly.png

Comment: It's F1 in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iwZLBynvv76sD20MRhzUJxKmFXpA1nh__FXXmIoRUoQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227984/discussion-between-reggyb-and-player0).